# React routing - NotFound component does not load in all cases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am a beginner in reactJS. I have the following routes defined in App.js

```
<Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
        <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} ></Route>
      </Switch>
</Router>
```

The `NotFound` component should be displayed for any invalid route. It works perfectly for all invalid route that looks like this

- localhost:3000/something_invalid
- localhost:3000/something_invalid_1

but if I add one more step to  the URL. The NotFound component is not getting rendered. e.g.,

- localhost:3000/something_invalid/something_invalid
- localhost:3000/something_invalid_1/something_invalid_1

What could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you importing `Router` or `BrowserRouter as Router`?

Comment: `import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
`

Comment: In that case, your code is perfectly valid and should work. Something else must be causing this. Do you have any other routes defined?

Comment: What exactly happens when you go to: `/something_invalid/something_invalid`? Anything in the console?

Comment: I have no other routes at the moment. In the console it gives me a 304 error.
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:101

Comment: How is your code different from this: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-tdd-xrmo3?file=/src/App.js You can try any path, the Not Found element gets rendered without any issues.

Comment: I ired https://xrmo3.csb.app/dashboard/dsds but it is still showing the dash page shouldn't  that be not found ? In your example.

Comment: That's because the dashboard path does not have the `exact` parameter set. That's not the point of your question though right? Your question is about `/something_invalid_1/something_invalid_1` not giving the Not Found. Am I wrong?

Comment: It is part of my question. I want to achieve the same in my code but even putting exact is not working

Comment: Well, try this now:  https://xrmo3.csb.app/dashboard/dsds I just put the `exact` param there.

Comment: the same doesn't work with my code. Perhaps it's the theme that I have integrated.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
    <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
    <Route component={NotFound} ></Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Code updated.

A 'Switch' renders the first child 'Route' that matches. A 'Route' without a path always matches.

The asterisk in your example is used in React-Router until version 3.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the root URL, it'll work as a catch all

Note that this works because it comes after your other defined routes, ie. `/dashboard` still works

```js
<Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
        <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="/" component={NotFound} ></Route>
      </Switch>
</Router>
```